# What is this component? It looks like a rectifier with 149k as identifier

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount, rectifier, component-selection

It looks like a rectifier with "pec" as manufacturer and 149k as identifier.

I am trying to look up the datasheet.

[image]

Comment: Note that you can simply right-click the above then "search image with google", and it will tell you what that is. Then you wouldn't have to wait 5 mins for an answer.

Comment: @dandavis: Using which browser?  Mine doesn't have that.

Comment: @JRE -- Then go manually to google.com, click on the image icon at the right side of the input field, copy the URL of the image there and you get the same treatment. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a Panjit DI108S surface mount glass passivated single phase bridge rectifier rated at 800V 1A.

Comment: 25 seconds before me

Answer (score 8):

It's a PANJIT International DI108S-PEC.

[LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Bridge-Rectifiers_PANJIT-International-DI108S-PEC_C263163.html)